# How to design database for fields like google forms?

Tags: django, postgresql, django-models, django-forms, django-admin

I want to build forms and models with dynamic fields like Google Form. But I don't know what type of model.Fields use for this task.
I using Postgres and I thinking about something like Hstore or ArrayField, but I'm not sure.

What is the best solution for this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are few solutions available for your task:

- [EAV (Entity-Attribute-Value) model](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Entity%E2%80%93attribute%E2%80%93value_model) with [django-eav](https://github.com/mvpdev/django-eav) package.
- Postgresql HSTORE field but it supports only string type of values.
- Postgresql JSON field.

If you use modern PostgreSQL version (9.3+) you should use PostgreSQL JSON fields because JSON supports different data types.